# Why Excel share workbook sometimes does not save changes?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We use Microsoft Excel 2016 share workbook. Our excel file is shared with samba and we access to our Windows via remote desktop. Sometimes we save changes but next time we can not find our changes.
What do you think about this problem?

Comment: Refer to this support article first: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/issue-when-save-excel-workbooks?tabs=third-party

Comment: Thanks, It was helpful.